# why does cout remove the trailing zeroes for floating point numbers

Tags: c++

So i have this code

```
template <typename T, typename T2>
void print (const T& a, const T2& b)
{
cout << a<<endl<<b<<endl ;
}

int main(){
float i=1.002;
float j=1.000;
print(i,j);

return 0;
}
```

the output is

```
 1.002
 1
```

what i dont get is why does cout remove the zeroes although i have specified 
them during initailisation , i know it wont make any difference but i m just curious why does it  happen.

Comment: "although i have specified them during " No you haven't. At compilation `1.000` is exactly the same as `1.0`or `1.00000000000000000`.

Comment: @rahul You seem to have serious misconceptions about data-representation and how these are converted to human readable text.

Comment: haha no no i just wanted to know if there is specific reason about this ,looking at the output of cout you cant figure out if its a float or int or double .i know floats how floats or ints or signed numbers or unsigned numbers are stored in the memory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the way the number is stored.

The [IEEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point/) floating point representation does not have a notion of significant digits. The numbers 1.0 or 1.000 all look the same in the binary notation.

You have to specify a precision when printing.

Python for instance does a type [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) that behaves like you want.

Comment: yeah this question came up in my mind after seeing python and auto keyword in c++11 std .

Answer (score 4):

- Because it's by design...?
- Usually, we don't like useless information in this world.
- And because `1.000 == 1`.

Comment: i get it but can you avoid the sarcasm ,i specifically said in the question that it doesn't make any difference i just wanted to know if there is something in documentation about this

Answer (score 2):

Expecting your code to print those trailing zeros is no different than expecting it to print `5.0 - 4.0` just because you initialized the variable as `float j = 5.0 - 4.0;`.

From the floating-point representation perspective, there's no such thing as "I specified trailing zeros during initialization". Floating-point numbers are not strings. They are numbers. And there are infinite different ways to express the same number as a sequence of human-readable characters in your program's text. In the source code of the program `1.000` is the same as `1.00` and is the same as `0.1e1` - they all represent the same number.

This means that when the time comes to convert a floating-point number back to the textual representation for `cout`, the library will not know (and will not care) what kind of text you used originally. You can affect the textual output by changing the precision, width and other format details (like use scientific format etc.), but there's no such thing as "output it the same way I wrote it in the source code".

Answer (score 0):

Why would it print `1.000` instead of `1.0000000000000000`? Both of those numbers are the same exact bits in memory. (In other words, a float value is stored as 32-bits in a very specific format. No matter if it is 1.0 or -59.12391 it is 32-bits of data in memory somewhere.)

If you want it to be printed in a certain way, use formatting specifiers such as `setw()` (don't forget to `#include<iomanip>`) to format your `cout` output a certain way.

Comment: so that's the reason are you sure?